# asp.net - Disable some content during certain period of time

Tags: asp.net, time

I want to change my content for example since 15:00 until 17:00. Disable labels or something like that. What can I use to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**VB.NET**

```
If DateTime.Now >= New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 15, 0, 0) AndAlso DateTime.Now <= New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 17, 0, 0) then
   MyPanel.Visible = false
End If
```

Contain the UI Elements, such as labels, that you want to hide within MyPanel.